# Test class design in Test Driven Development

Tags: tdd

I am trying to make sense of TDD. Say I am going to write multiple test classes along with tens of methods for a small project. There will be hundreds of combinations of test classes and methods that work.Are there best practices, standards or guidance on what test classes there should be? Similarly, any on methods of each class?

I involves in the full lifecycle of web application development.Any recommendations on books or training? Thank you in advance!

Comment: As I understand it, TDD is iterative and you can gradually adjust how you organise your test classes. For more general strategies, you may refer to the following book:

Meszaros, Gerard. xUnit test patterns: Refactoring test code. Pearson Education, 2007.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Will take a look at xUnit test patterns.

Answer (score 1):

In TDD, you don't "plan" to write hundreds of combinations of test classes.  What you do is take one of your requirements (often just a tiny subset of a requirement), and write one test that proves it's been met.  Your test will fail, because your code doesn't do that yet.  Next, you write a little bit of code, just enough to pass the test.  And then you refactor that code you just wrote - the goal of this refactoring is to remove duplication, to follow good OO design principles, and to make your code fit your application's architecture.

What you'll find is that you'll think about coding differently.  You stop trying to plan out every class in advance.  You don't generate huge UML diagrams.  Instead, you grow your product to match more and more of your requirements.  When all your requirements are met, the code is done.

Getting to your more specific questions, what we do is to have a one-to-one relationship between test classes and production classes.  I'm a fan of naming the test classes by suffixing _Test to the class name:  the tests for ShippingClass become ShippingClass_Test.  That makes the tests for a class easy to find.  Inside ShippingClass_Test, there will be several test methods for each method of ShippingClass.  Each test method exercises a different flow through the production method.  Let's say there's a CalculateShippingFees() method and this requirement has to deal with taxes, tax exempt, and international shipping.  Each part of the requirements will drive a new little bit of logic that will result in another test.  I might get as far as writing a CalculateShippingFees_TaxExempt_Test, CalculateShippingFees_Taxable_Test, and a CalculateShippingFees_TaxServiceOffline_Test (always write tests for your error handling paths, too.)

But when I get to CalculateShippingFees_International_Test, as I'm refactoring I realize that there are more destinations than I thought, and the method is growing too big.  So maybe I extract the destinations into a new class using the Strategy pattern, and then I start writing tests for each of those.  Or maybe I discover that our shipping provider has a fee calculator that I can leverage, so I change the code to use it.  Making these changes is quick and easy, because I know that as long as all my tests pass, I can change anything I want!

And that's the point of TDD:  you evolve the software to meet your needs as you need them.  If I built up a giant mental model that said "I'll need a shipping fee tax class, and an international destination, a domestic destination, a customs fee calculator, blah blah blah", I may spend a lot of time building all those classes only to later discover that the shipping provider has an API that gives me all that stuff for free, and I wasted my time writing it. Or maybe I screwed up the initial design, thinking that customs fees would be a part of shipping instead of a part of international destinations.  With TDD, as I add the new methods and classes, I put them where I need them when I need them.

There are several good books on the topic.  Like @Franck, I also recommend Mezaros' [xUnit Test Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FMW67IY). Roy Osherove has a pretty good book [The Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290890).  And Freeman and Pryce have [Growing Object Oriented Software Guided By Tests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627).  Kent Beck's book, [Test Driven Development by Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) was kind of the spark and it's pretty easy to follow, but it's getting old and the practices of TDD have evolved past it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess would be better if you start to write your code and you show us where do you think you will have tons of combinations, the recommended books are really awesome and also you will have to take advantage of what unit testing framework are you using, junit(Java) supports parameters for those combinations and Spock(groovy) uses parameter tables that are really awesome